# Request.QueryString to grab url param value

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to access to url content from razor view. I want to grab content from param name, so I want to grab only Pasat91

```
http://localhost:4853/Details/Wind?name=Pasat91
```

I tried with

```
@{ var a = Request.QueryString["name"]; }
```

but I'm getting an empty string.

Comment: Assume you mean _grab only Pasat91_? Works fine for me.

Comment: yes, I mean Pasat91. I should check again then.

Comment: You should capture that in your controller, then pass it to the view with a `ViewBag` or `ViewData`

Comment: Request.QueryString["name"] works for me. You can give a try `Request.RequestContext.RouteData.DataTokens["name"]` to check if it resolve your problem.